# Single panel lattice plot with axis on the right (and bottom)

Tags: r, lattice

Seems like it should be a simple thing to do, but I'm not finding a solution.  I want a basic single lattice plot to have the axis labels on the right (and bottom), not on the left (and bottom).  There are lot of solutions involving multiple panels, but I'm dealing with a single panel.  Seems like this must require invoking `panel.axis` but my attempts lead to errors, or no complaints, but no change to the plot.

```
library("lattice")
set.seed(123)
DF <- data.frame(x = runif(5), y = runif(5))

xyplot(y ~ x, data = DF) # default is axes labeled on left and bottom
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't seem to find a more direct way to do this, but you can create a custom `axis` function that controls where values are placed. Here's an example

```
myaxis <- function(side, labels="default", ticks="default", ...) {
  default <- lattice.getOption("default.args")$axis
  if(side %in% c("right","bottom")) {
    default(side=side, labels="yes", ticks="yes", ...)
  } else {
    default(side=side, labels="no", ticks="yes", ...)
  }
}
```

Then you use it like so

```
xyplot(y ~ x, data = DF, axis=myaxis)
```

to get

[image]

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick This gets the job done, and allows some additional control.  Looks like it updates the default axis specification which is actually a function, with new defaults.  Seems strange that there isn't a simpler way to specifiy this sort of change.  Does make me feel better, though, that I wasn't finding a solution.  I will allow a bit more time in case someone has another approach.